# Can second degree polynomials generate as many as we wish prime numbers in the way described?

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

While I was getting in my pyjamas, a few minutes ago, the Euler polynomial $n^2+n+41$ came into my mind. As you know, this polynomial is famous because the set $\{f(0),f(1),...f(39)\}$ consists of prime numbers only, so this polynomial takes for the first $40$ of its values on the set $\mathbb N_0$ only prime numbers.

So the natural question to ask is:

> Is it true that for every $m \in \mathbb N$ there exists second degree real polynomial of a real variable $P$ and a number $k(m) \in \mathbb N$ such that all numbers in the set $\{P(k(m)), P(k(m)+1),...,P(k(m)+m-1)\}$ are prime numbers?

Comment: Note that by argument translation you can assume $k(m)=0$ to simplify the statement.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you, but does it simplify it really or it makes it look simpler?

Comment: Great context to the question. +1

Answer (score 23):

Yes. In fact, you don't even need the quadratic term: there are degree-$1$ polynomials giving arbitrarily long sequences of primes by the Green-Tao theorem. (Of course, you could also let $P$ be a constant prime).

Comment: But I wrote second degree because I want them to be of second degree, not of degree one or degree zero.

Comment: @Farewell OK. Take a linear function $f(X)$, and replace $X \rightarrow X^2,$ if you really want to.

Comment: Yes, indeed. . +1

Comment: Replacing a linear with $X \to X^2$ is not the nicest solution, because people still do not know if there are infinitely many primes of the form $X^2+1$ for instance. I don't think any general quadratics of this form are known to have this property yet (though conjectured of course).

Comment: @Supersingularity The polynomials are not supposed to take infinitely many prime values, but rather arbitrarily long (finite) prime progressions.

Comment: @user334871. Re : Your 1st comment....At first that didn't seem right, but it is. As there are arbitrarily long arithmetic sequences of primes (Green & Tao,2004), if $a\ne 0$ and $aX +b=a(X-m)+(a m +b)$  is prime for $X=m,m+1,,...,m+n$ then  $a Y^2 +a m+b$ is prime for $0\leq Y\leq \sqrt n. $

Answer (score 17):

This follows by the [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem): there exist arbitrarily long arithmetic sequences of primes.
If $$ak+b,a(k+1)+b,\ldots,a(k+m^2)+b$$ are prime, we can take
$P(n)=a(k+n^2)+b$, being prime for $n=0,\ldots,m$.

Note that the same works if we require $\deg P=1$.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, this argument would work for polynomials of any degree?

Comment: Yes, indeed.${}$

Comment: I suspect that answering the Q without using the Green-Tao theorem may be as difficult  proving the Green-Tao theorem.

Comment: Is the Tao Ziegler paper not cleaner for polynomials? https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610050

Answer (score 2):

If you allow non-monic polynomials the question is not very arithmetic in nature.

Any class of integer functions closed under the operations $f(n) \to Af(n)+B$ with integer $A,B$, is guaranteed to have this property for any set that contains long arithmetic progressions (such as the primes,  by the Green/Tao theorem as people have mentioned).  This includes degree $k$ polynomials for any $k$.

For monic non-linear polynomials, as long as $f(n)$ does not assume all values mod $p$ for some prime, then for all $k$ there is an integer $A$ such that $(f(x) + A)$ has no congruence obstruction to having a string of $k$ consecutive prime values. According to the the Hypothesis H conjectures (Schinzel, Bateman-Horn) such strings then occur infinitely often.